# How to i make it so that every time it reaches 10 it plays a sound, so 10, 20, 30, 40

Tags: java

```java
if (score == 10) {
    Sound.soundScore1();
```

I am a newbie programmer, so if this is a stupid question, sorry but if you don't ask you don't know.
What i want the code to do is when you reach the score of 10, 20, 30, 40... it plays a different sound to the regular ping noise. That there is my current code, is there any way of doing what i said??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (score % 10 == 0) {
    Sound.soundScore1();
}
```

meaning, if the remainder of the division by 10 (aka modulus operator `%`) is 0.

Answer (score 2):

The Remainder operator(%) is the appropriate way to carry out the functionality.
It is also called the Modulo operator.

It is a binary operator.

Please find the below link for more information.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

The below code would help you achieve it.

```
if(score%10 == 0){
Sound.soundScore1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although modulus `%` solution is fine, it costs a lot. It could be faster to check if the last digit is a 0. An example below. You can avoid creating a boolean variable. Also if you already have a string, you can avoid first conversion from int to String (this often happens in videogames world when you want to display a score on some GUI labels).

```
int iNumber = 665;
String sNumber = String.valueOf(iNumber);
boolean bResult = (sNumber.substring(sNumber.length() - 1)).equals("0");
System.out.println(bResult);
```

Comment: and how would you suggest doing that technically? :)

Comment: I'm pretty confident that converting an int to a string (don't forget allocating the string), costs **a lot** more than modulus (which simply does division). saying modulus costs more is like saying that division costs more than conversion to a string. btw, equals returns true / false. don't need to use `?:` ternary operator.